# zappa {"message":"Forbidden"} using flask

Tags: amazon-web-services, zappa

I have a flask app that i'm able to deploy on aws using Zappa . A simple Hello World works fine but  when my app redirected to a uri not including the environment name (/uri instead of /dev/uri) i get a Forbidden error.

```
app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
    
           
@app.route("/upload", methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == "POST":
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, secure_filename(f.filename)))
        upload_file(f"uploads/{f.filename}", BUCKET)
        return redirect("/")
```

The above upload method fails while accessing giving me a **{"message":"Forbidden"}** Error

I think it has to do something with the URI not being right because Zappa adds 'dev' path during deployment ..

Answer (score 0):

The developer has stated several times that a domain name is needed to overcome the addition of "/dev" and "/production". You can try following what's on this page.

[GitHub issue with some response](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1317)

Comment: correct ! i should have mentioned that i have already looked at the above article but as per the article a custom domain name should  be created by Zappa but i do not see any .. i need some direction on how i should be created one if needed